# Windows 8 upgrade on TrueCrypt encrypted system disk?

Tags: windows-8, truecrypt, windows-8-upgrade

I have Windows 7 on encrypted system disk (I have to enter password before getting to system boot).
I suppose there is a driver loaded so Windows can read encrypted data and continue booting.

Will upgrade to Windows 8 succeed? I'm a bit worried about that driver and system transition.

Comment: Decrypt the drive first. Windows 8 uses a different boot loader than previous versions, so this is the recommended method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decrypt the drive completely before attempting the install: others have reported [problems](https://superuser.com/questions/493728/upgrade-to-windows-8-on-encrypted-drive-fails-and-corrupted-my-truecrypt-bios-pa/) with installing Windows 8 on a TrueCrypt volume.